# Springboot evaluate api path from Controller method name

Tags: spring-boot, rest

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/orders/")
public class OrderController {

@PostMapping("create")
public ResponseEntity<OrderResponseV2> create(
        @RequestBody OrderRequestV2 orderRequest) {
    OrderResponse response = createOrderService.createOrder(orderRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
}
```

Is there a way to get the whole API path including root context during runtime using Relfection from class+method name?

Comment: Yes, there is a way using reflection just by reading those annotations.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the API path, you can use `request.getURL(), request.getURI()` or want to perform other action?

Comment: I don't have the request object available. Possible to get it through spring. Similar to what swagger does.